# Local analysis issue in Sonar Eclipse plugin

Tags: sonarqube

When I do the local analysis in sonar eclipse plugin, I'm getting the following output in the console

**Registered 104 metrics

Registered repository findbugs/java with 384 rules

Registered repository checkstyle/java with 122 rules

Registered repository pmd/java with 224 rules

Registered repository squid/java with 12 rules**

and then an error

**An internal error occurred during: "Sonar Analysis".
org.sonar.wsclient.connectors.ConnectionException: Can not read response**

Can anyone help me out with this?

**Edit**:I tried in both modes "Run as normal user" and "Run as administrator". One more thing is it is working in Windows7 and not in Vista. Is it OS problem?

**Edit**:Getting this stack trace in the sonar console

```
jvm 1    | 2012-03-27 04:30:49.146:INFO::org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager$Sele
ctSet@a0199a JVM BUG(s) - recreating selector 1 times, canceled keys 0 times
jvm 1    | 2012-03-27 04:31:14.306:WARN:/:Error: Couldn't handle error: response
 committed
jvm 1    | org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: Native Exception: 'class org.mor
tbay.jetty.EofException'; Message: timeout; StackTrace: org.mortbay.jetty.EofExc
eption: timeout<|?at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.blockForOutput(A
bstractGenerator.java:547)<|?at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.flush
(AbstractGenerator.java:571)<|?at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$Output.flush(
HttpConnection.java:1010)<|?at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.write(
AbstractGenerator.java:650)<|?at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.writ
e(AbstractGenerator.java:590)<|?at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(
Native Method)<|?at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)<
|?at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)<|?at java.l
ang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)<|?at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.
invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:525)<|
jvm 1    |      at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.blockForOutput(Abs
tractGenerator.java:547)
jvm 1    |      at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.flush(AbstractGene
rator.java:571)
jvm 1    |      at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$Output.flush(HttpConnection.
java:1010)
jvm 1    |      at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.write(AbstractGene
rator.java:650)
jvm 1    |      at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.write(AbstractGene
rator.java:590)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Sourc
e)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHan
dling(JavaMethod.java:525)
```

**Edit:** Tried by changing database from derby to mysql but of no use. But **Java Runner** is working okay. Why the eclipse plug-in is failing?

Comment: look at this Issue, it may help you [SONARIDE-192](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARIDE-192)

Comment: @ChandraSekhar I am not getting NPE. I am getting "Can not read response" and there is no reason why it is giving that error.

Comment: Ravindra, can you try to catch the HTTP request that is sent to the Sonar server and that fails? I can't see from the log where it can come from.

Also, this is weird that it works on Win7 but not on Vista, as nothing is OS specific. Are you sure you have exactly the same configuration?

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarTeam Yes I am using Eclipse Indigo in both Win7 and Vista and it is failing only in vista.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarTeam Should I reinstall eclipse and sonar plug-in again?

Comment: You can try. That would also help if you could paste a longer stack-trace (the one you get in Sonar) as it is not possible to know the root cause from the excerpt you gave.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarTeam I posted the complete stack trace which I got in the Server. Let me try re-installing Eclipse and sonar plug-in. Thanks for the support.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarTeam Tried reinstalling eclipse and sonar. But no luck.

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli Can you try to catch the HTTP request that is sent to the Sonar server and that fails? And compare it to the one that succeeds on Win7.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarTeam Can you guide me how can I do that?

Comment: You should activate the http request logs on the Web server on which Sonar is running. By default, this is Jetty and you can find plenty of documentation on the Internet on how to achieve that (e.g. http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Logging+Requests)

Comment: I am running sonar as a standalone application and not on a web server. In that I could find only jar files. I am not able to find any xml file where I can enable the http request log. Now I'm trying to run sonar in Tomcat7.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9466/discussion-between-ravindra-gullapalli-and-fabrice-sonar-team)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running in tomcat solved my issue. Now I am able to use Sonar in Windows vista too. Procedure to configure sonar in tomcat is very simple and is available in [Sonar Installation Instructions](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installation+in+4+steps). Check **Mode 2 - Deploy on Java EE Server** in that page. If not working, just login into sonar as admin/admin and go to configure and change the default quality profile between **Sonar way** and **Sonar way with Findbugs**. This worked for me.